# Text Hashing trick produces different results in Python and C#

Tags: c#, python, nlp

I am trying to move a trained model into a production environment and have encountered an issue trying to replicate the behavior of the Keras hashing_trick() function in C#. When I go to encode the sentence my output is different in C# than it is in python:

Text: "Information - The configuration processing is completed."

Python: [  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0   0   0 217 142 262 113 319 413]

C#: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 433, 426, 425, 461, 336, 146, 52]

(copied from debugger, both sequences have length 30)

What I've tried:

1. changing the encoding of the text bytes in C# to match the python string.encode() function default (UTF8)
2. Changing capitalization of letters to lowercase and upper case
3. Tried using Convert.ToUInt32 instead of BitConverter (resulted in overflow error)

My code (below) is my implementation of the Keras hashing_trick function. A single input sentence is given and then the function will return the corresponding encoded sequence.

```
public uint[] HashingTrick(string data)
    {
        const int VOCAB_SIZE = 534; //Determined through python debugging of model
        var filters = "!#$%&()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~\t\n".ToCharArray().ToList();
        filters.ForEach(x =>
        {
            data = data.Replace(x, '\0');
        });
        string[] parts = data.Split(' ');
        var encoded = new List<uint>();
        parts.ToList().ForEach(x =>
        {

            using (System.Security.Cryptography.MD5 md5 = System.Security.Cryptography.MD5.Create())
            {
                byte[] inputBytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(x);
                byte[] hashBytes = md5.ComputeHash(inputBytes);


                uint val = BitConverter.ToUInt32(hashBytes, 0);
                encoded.Add(val % (VOCAB_SIZE - 1) + 1);
            }
        });
        return PadSequence(encoded, 30);

    }
    private uint[] PadSequence(List<uint> seq, int maxLen)
    {
        if (seq.Count < maxLen)
        {
            while (seq.Count < maxLen)
            {
                seq.Insert(0, 0);
            }
            return seq.ToArray();
        }
        else if (seq.Count > maxLen)
        {
            return seq.GetRange(seq.Count - maxLen - 1, maxLen).ToArray();
        }
        else
        {
            return seq.ToArray();
        }
    }
```

The keras implementation of the hashing trick can be found [here](https://github.com/keras-team/keras-preprocessing/blob/master/keras_preprocessing/text.py)

If it helps, I am using an ASP.NET Web API as my solution type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The biggest problem with your code is that it fails to account for the fact that Python's `int` is an arbitrary precision integer, while C#'s `uint` has only 32 bits. This means that Python is calculating the modulo over all 128 bits of the hash, while C# is not (and `BitConverter.ToUInt32` is the wrong thing to do in any case, as the endianness is wrong). The other problem that trips you up is that `\0` does not terminate strings in C#, and `\0` can't just be added to an MD5 hash without changing the outcome.

Translated in as straightforward a manner as possible:

```
int[] hashingTrick(string text, int n, string filters, bool lower, string split) {
    var splitWords = String.Join("", text.Where(c => !filters.Contains(c)))
        .Split(new[] { split }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

    return (
        from word in splitWords
        let bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(lower ? word.ToLower() : word)
        let hash = MD5.Create().ComputeHash(bytes)
        // add a 0 byte to force a non-negative result, per the BigInteger docs 
        let w = new BigInteger(hash.Reverse().Concat(new byte[] { 0 }).ToArray())
        select (int) (w % (n - 1) + 1)
    ).ToArray();
}
```

Sample use:

```
const int vocabSize = 534;
Console.WriteLine(String.Join(" ",
    hashingTrick(
        text: "Information - The configuration processing is completed.",
        n: vocabSize,
        filters: "!#$%&()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~\t\n",
        lower: true,
        split: " "
    ).Select(i => i.ToString())
));
```

```
217 142 262 113 319 413
```

This code has various inefficiencies: filtering characters with LINQ is very inefficient compared to using a `StringBuilder` and we don't really need `BigInteger` here since MD5 is always exactly 128 bits, but optimizing (if necessary) is left as an exercise to the reader, as is padding the outcome (which you already have a function for).

Comment: Thank you for the example! It appears that this code works for smaller sentences (like the one in the question) but for large sentences with more detail (lets just assume that these sentences can go over 100 words) the output is not correct. Is this due to the fact that I have a larger string and therefore many more bits to hash across?

Comment: I don't know where the magic number `534` comes from -- that'd be my first line of investigation. Second is to look at which numbers *are* correct -- every integer corresponds to one hashed word in the above code, so if there are differences this is due to the string getting split up differently, or the results gathered up differently. I didn't debug the Python code very closely. (For example, try "configuration configuration configuration" -- does Python produce three numbers or just one?)

Comment: As an aside, depending on your application, you may want to take a look at something like [IronPython](http://ironpython.net/) to run your Python code directly, instead of translating the code first into C# (you can use C# to provide the API endpoint, and call the Python code, in the same application). Reinventing the wheel is never a good idea, especially if the current wheel is perfectly functional.

Comment: The magic number 534 comes from the number of total distinct words in the data set I am working with. This number is used to create the hashes as well as in an embedding layer within a Keras model. I tried to use IronPython, but the hashlib library used by Keras is not supported in IronPython. This is due to the fact that hashlib is a C extension which are not supported by IronPython. I am investigating a project called ironclad which aims to fix this issue. I'll report back with results.

Comment: @MichaelGeorge: IronPython code should be able to call any .NET class, so you may actually be able to replace `hashlib` with a call to .NET's own `MD5` class, which requires minimal code adjustments (assuming it's using MD5 throughout).

Comment: My initial impression of your idea is that we would just be moving the issue to a different spot. However, you do have a point in your answer where you point out that python handles the integer class differently than C#. I am not sure it would be worth using the .NET MD5 function especially because executing embedded python code seems like it would significantly slow down the system anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of solving the issue of trying to fight with C# to get the hashing right, I took a different approach to the problem. When making my data set to train the model (this is a machine learning project after all) I decided to use @Jeron Mostert's implementation of the hashing function to pre-hash the data set before feeding it into the model.

This solution was much easier to implement and ended up working just as well as the original text hashing. Word of advice for those attempting to do cross language hashing like me: Don't do it, it's a lot of headache! Use one language for hashing your text data and find a way to create a valid data set with all of the information required.